# Find parameters of ODEs to fit solution data

Tags: fitting

## Problem

How to find the initial conditions `x[0]`,`y[0]` and the optimal value of parameters `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` to fit the following system of ODEs?

```
 x'[t] ==  a*x[t] - b*x[t]*y[t]
 y'[t] == -c*y[t] + d*x[t] y[t]
```

Solution data is:

```
    (* The first column is time 't', the second column is coordinate 'x', and the last
    column is coordinate 'y'. *)
data = {{11, 45.79, 41.4},    {12, 53.03, 38.9},    {13, 64.05, 36.78}, 
        {14, 75.4, 36.04},    {15, 90.36, 33.78},   {16, 107.14, 35.4},
        {17, 127.79, 34.68},  {18, 150.77, 36.61},  {19, 179.65, 37.71},
        {20, 211.82, 41.98},  {21, 249.91, 45.72},  {22, 291.31, 53.1},
        {23, 334.95, 65.44},  {24, 380.67, 83.},    {25, 420.28, 108.74},
        {26, 445.56, 150.01}, {27, 447.63, 205.61}, {28, 414.04, 281.6},
        {29, 347.04, 364.56}, {30, 265.33, 440.3},  {31, 187.57, 489.68},
        {32, 128., 512.95},   {33, 85.25, 510.01},  {34, 57.17, 491.06},
        {35, 39.96, 462.22},  {36, 29.22, 430.15},  {37, 22.3, 396.95},
        {38, 16.52, 364.87},  {39, 14.41, 333.16},  {40, 11.58, 304.97},
        {41, 10.41, 277.73},  {42, 10.17, 253.16},  {43, 7.86, 229.66},
        {44, 9.23, 209.53},   {45, 8.22, 190.07},   {46, 8.76, 173.58},
        {47, 7.9, 156.4},     {48, 8.38, 143.05},   {49, 9.53, 130.75},
        {50, 9.33, 117.49},   {51, 9.72, 108.16},   {52, 10.55, 98.08},
        {53, 13.05, 88.91},   {54, 13.58, 82.28},   {55, 16.31, 75.42},
        {56, 17.75, 69.58},   {57, 20.11, 62.58},   {58, 23.98, 59.22},
        {59, 28.51, 54.91},   {60, 31.61, 49.79},   {61, 37.13, 45.94},
        {62, 45.06, 43.41},   {63, 53.4, 41.3},     {64, 62.39, 40.28},
        {65, 72.89, 37.71},   {66, 86.92, 36.58},   {67, 103.32, 36.98},
        {68, 121.7, 36.65},   {69, 144.86, 37.87},  {70, 171.92, 39.63},
        {71, 202.51, 42.97},  {72, 237.69, 46.95},  {73, 276.77, 54.93},
        {74, 319.76, 64.61},  {75, 362.05, 81.28},  {76, 400.11, 105.5},
        {77, 427.79, 143.03}, {78, 434.56, 192.45}, {79, 410.31, 260.84},
        {80, 354.18, 339.39}, {81, 278.49, 413.79}, {82, 203.72, 466.94},
        {83, 141.06, 494.72}, {84, 95.08, 499.37},  {85, 66.76, 484.58},
        {86, 45.41, 460.63},  {87, 33.13, 429.79},  {88, 25.89, 398.77},
        {89, 20.51, 366.49},  {90, 17.11, 336.56},  {91, 12.69, 306.39},
        {92, 11.76, 279.53},  {93, 11.22, 254.95},  {94, 10.29, 233.5},
        {95, 8.82, 212.74},   {96, 9.51, 193.61},   {97, 8.69, 175.01},
        {98, 9.53, 160.59},   {99, 8.68, 146.12},   {100, 10.82, 131.85}};
```

I have tried `ParametricNDSolveValue` but get a lot error message. Can you help me?

### Solution(up to now)

We now have a **direct method** to solve this problem. The main idea is interpolating
many points from `t=11` to `t=100`, then get the value of `dx/dt` and `dy/dt` by Finite
Difference method(with minor time step, this can decrease the loss of accuracy). Finally,
just use `FindFit` twice to get parameters `a`, `b` and `c`, `d`. So that system of ODEs
can be determined, but how can we find `x[0]` and `y[0]`? Just solve the system backward using `NDSolve` or `NDSolveValue`.

```
{t, x, y} = Transpose[data]; (* extract data *)
{xdata, ydata} = (Transpose[{t, #}]) & /@ {x, y}; (* get {t,x} and {t,y} pairs *)
fx = Interpolation[xdata, Method -> "Spline"];  (* spline interpolation *)
fy = Interpolation[ydata, Method -> "Spline"];
dx=fx'[t];
dy=fy'[t];
ab=FindFit[Transpose[{fx[t], fy[t], dx}], a*X - b*X Y, {a, b}, {X, Y}]
cd=FindFit[Transpose[{fx[t], fy[t], dy}], -c*Y + d*X Y, {c, d}, {X, Y}]
```

Here we get `{a -> 0.213493, b -> 0.00119763}` and `{c -> 0.104194, d -> 0.000950553}`.
As I put above, use `NDSolve` to find `x[0]` and `y[0]`.

```
(* search backward *)
NDSolve[{X'[u] == a*X[u] - b*X [u] Y[u] /. ab,  Y'[u] == -c*Y[u] + d*X[u] Y[u] /. cd,    
         X[11] == 45.79, Y[11] == 41.4}, {X[0], Y[0]}, {u, 0, 12}]
```

It returns `{{X[0] -> 10.415, Y[0] -> 102.984}}`.

Let's see the plot:

```
(* find solution of x[t], y[t] with NDSolveValue *)
sol = NDSolveValue[{X'[u] == a*X[u] - b*X [u]Y[u] /. ab,Y'[u] == -c*Y[u] + d*X[u]Y[u] /. cd,
X[11] == 45.79, Y[11] == 41.4}, {{u, X[u]}, {u, Y[u]}}, {u, 11, 100}]
(* plot the results *)
Show[{ListPlot[{xdata, ydata}, AxesLabel -> {"time", "value"},
      PlotLegends -> {"xdata", "ydata"}, PlotStyle -> {Red, Green}],
ListLinePlot[{Table[sol[[1]], {u, 11, 100, 0.01}], Table[sol[[2]], {u, 11, 100, 0.01}]},
      PlotStyle -> {Orange, Blue}, PlotLegends -> {"solution.x", "solution.y"}]}]
```

[image: see the results]

It is obvious that scaters at the peaks and valleys are off the curves a little. This implies us that the result is not good enough and there exists improved space of the
*direct method*. Can you image how difficult it would be using FDM when the system of ODEs is of much higher order? We must find out an universal way to solve this kind of problem.

---

Here we show another way:

```
{tval, xval, yval} = Transpose[data]; (*extract data*)
{xdata, ydata} = (Transpose[{t, #}]) & /@ {xval, yval }; (*get {t,x} and {t,y} pairs*)
(* define the embeded function with arguments a,b,c,d *)
px[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ] := (modle[a, b, c, d] = 
    First[x /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x [t] y[t], 
               x[11] == 45.79, y[11] == 41.70}, x, {t, 10, 100}]]);
FindFit[xdata, px[a, b, c, d][t], {{a, .1}, {b, .1}, {c, .1}, {d, .1}}, t]
py[a_?NumberQ, b_?NumberQ, c_?NumberQ, d_?NumberQ] := (model[a, b, c, d] = 
    First[x /. NDSolve[{x'[t] == a x[t] - b x[t] y[t], y'[t] == -c y[t] + d x [t] y[t], 
               x[11] == 45.79, y[11] == 41.70}, y, {t, 10, 100}]]);
FindFit[ydata, py[a, b, c, d][t], {{a, .1}, {b, .1}, {c, .1}, {d, .1}}, t]
```

Unfortulately, it doesn't work. We need a *good initial value* for `a`, `b`, `c`, `d`, or will fail to do the fitting work. Maybe we could take a chance to get *good value* with the help of `NSolve` or `FindInstance`.

Comment: This might be stupid, but - off the top of my head... Instead of solving the ODEs system, since we have approximated values of x[t] and y[t], from which approximated values of the derivatives can be computed, why not substituting these values four at the time to solve for the four unknowns a,b,c and d? Will the average solutions found over the whole sweep of values be a sensible guess for a, b, c and d?

Comment: @Peltio I like that, even if the guess isn't good enough it will be a great starting value for `FindRoot`

Comment: @Peltio This problem is just a simple demo for solving parameters fitting of ODEs with `ParametricNDSolveValue`. With data set above, we can get parameters `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` by finding a analytic solution(if exists) or simply compute derivatives by difference for substitution into those equations above.

Comment: I am not familiar with ParametricNDSolveValue, but this kind of problems can suffer from lack of precision in the data. After all predator-prey systems are used to exemplify the sensitivity of solutions from initial data, right? With my silly method I get a wide range of values for the parameters, and my tentative solution (a=0.222, b=0.01, c=0.1, d=0.001) is probably way off.

Comment: Well, my method is not that silly after all. I refined it to get `{a -> 0.214, b -> 0.00122, c -> 0.105, d -> 0.00095}`. If you solve the system with this parameters and plot it along with the points you have given you will find that on 0-100 it is a very good fit. Initial values are not integers though (`x[0]=10.55` and `y[0]=103.84`), but hey, there could always be a lion with two heads and a gazelle with three legs.

Comment: @Peltio I agree with you about the sensitivity of solutions from initial data. And I get `a=0.2134; b=0.0012; c=0.1042; d=0.00095055` with _MATLAB_. I did not get `x[0],y[0]`, but here is a result for reference:`x0=10.6693503042249,y0=104.90513939744`

Comment: Since I am not that much off, I posted my answer. It can still be improved in many way but I believe it could be a useful starting point

Comment: Two things:  1 - what is `modle`? and 2 - Why don't you use the output of the first method as an input for the second one? Also, I believe you should define a measure of the error in the approximate solution, in order to be able to compare methods.

Comment: @Peltio Just a typing mistake. It should be `model`. I have put that, I just want to get an universal method to solve this kind of problem, however I can't use the first method because of higher order system of ODEs. Say, a 4th ODE with 2 parameters and solution data, it's unwise to use the first method with that.

Answer (score 1):

This is a 'brute force' method but it seems to work.
I start with extracting the data:

```
{tvals, xvals, yvals} = Transpose[data];
{xdata,ydata} = (Transpose[{tvals, #}])& /@ {xvals, yvals};
```

I then compute their interpolating functions, since I will be needing an approximate value for the derivatives:

```
xf = Interpolation[xdata];
yf = Interpolation[ydata];
```

Evaluating this will show that the derivative of the interpolations are somewhat rough

```
Plot[{xf'[t], yf'[t]}, {t, 11, 100}, Frame -> True, PlotRange -> All]
```

Since we know that this sort of problems have smooth solutions, a **possible improvement** could be to change `xf'` and `yf'` with a smoothed version that might be affected by less error, but I won't do that now.

The brute force idea consists in generating sets of four linear equations in the coefficients `a`, `b`, `c` and `d` and then - if the system admits a unique solution - get these solutions to get an idea about their actual values. Evaluating the system of ODEs

> ```
> coeffSystem[t_] := {
>       xf'[t] == a*xf[t] - b*xf[t]*yf[t],
>       yf'[t] == -c*yf[t] + d*xf[t] yf[t]
>       };
> ```

at two subsequent times t1 and t2 will produce the four linear algebraic equations we need.

> ```
> solvableSys[t1_, t2_] := Flatten[coeffSystem /@ {t1, t2}]
> ```

I have named this procedure `solvableSys` because I intended to embed a check on the determinant to make sure the system would produce a unique solution but then, it's faster to solve anyway and then discard what we do not like.
A **possible improvement** would be selecting only 'good' systems if this can be done in a way to speed thing up.

Now, the brute force I am using here is probably an overkill but it help in producing good looking graphs for the coefficient values :-)
I am solving for all pairs of `t1`, `t2`. This will produce a very long list of substitution rules

> ```
> paramRules = Table[
>       Flatten[Solve[solvableSys[t1, t2]]], {t1, 11, 99}, {t2, t1 + 1, 100}];
> ```

from which I will extract the values for `a`, `b`, `c`, and `d` (the last substitution is to take care of the unsolvable or undetermined systems - the rude method I use to infer the solution is not affected by a bunch of added zeros).

```
{rawAdata, rawBdata, rawCdata, rawDdata} = 
    (Flatten[# /. paramRules] /. # -> 0) & /@ {a, b, c, d};
```

If you plot these lists of values you will see that there is a somewhat large dispersion but the values are insisting on a given line. That's what I elected to be the actual value of the parameter.
Plotting the sorted data can give a clearer view of what is happening

```
{ {ListPlot[ Sort[rawAdata] ], ListPlot[ Sort[rawBdata] ]},
  {ListPlot[ Sort[rawCdata] ], ListPlot[ Sort[rawDdata], ]} }
```

At this point we can extract the estimate of our parameters by inspection just by locating the inflection points and reading the parameter value on the vertical axis (the horizontal axis has no particular meaning). Doing this will get you

```
paramEstimate = {a -> 0.214, b -> 0.00122, c -> 0.105, d -> 0.00095}
```

(A **better method would be** computing the interpolating functions of the sorted values, and then solving for the value where their derivative is zero. The corresponding ordinate is the solution). The solution of the system on 0-100, computed with conditions at `t=11`, the first available point in the data, will give:

```
Clear[x, y];
{x[t_], y[t_]} = {x[t], y[t]} /. NDSolve[{
     x'[t] == a*x[t] - b*x[t]*y[t],
     y'[t] == -c*y[t] + d*x[t]*y[t],
     x[11] == 45.79, y[11] == 41.4 } /. paramEstimate,
    {x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}][[1]];
```

This solution appears to be a good fit of the supplied data over the interval 0-100.

```
pdata = ListPlot[{xdata, ydata}]; 
solved = Plot[{x[t], y[t]}, {t, 0, 100}];
Show[pdata,solved]
```

The initial values at t=0 are

```
{x[0], y[0]}
   (* 10.555, 103.839 *)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
tt = data[[All, 1]]; 
x = data[[All, 2]]; 
y = data[[All, 3]]; 
(* finite difference approximation of derivative *)
dx = (RotateLeft[#1] - #1 & )[x]; 
dy = (RotateLeft[#1] - #1 & )[y]; 
(* Use the least-squares optimization *)
err[a_, b_, c_, d_] = Sum[
     (dx[[t]] - a*x[[t]] + b*x[[t]]*y[[t]])^2 + 
     (dy[[t]] + c*x[[t]] - d*x[[t]]*y[[t]])^2,
     {t, -1 + Length[tt]}]; 
(* Set the gradient (with respect to parameters) to zero and solve *)
NSolve[{D[err[a, b, c, d], a] == 0, D[err[a, b, c, d], b] == 0, 
        D[err[a, b, c, d], c] == 0, D[err[a, b, c, d], d] == 0}, {a, b, c, d}]
(* Output *)
{{a -> 0.197193, b -> 0.00117457, c -> -0.0562289, d -> 0.000277672}}
```

I just saw that you also wanted `x0` and `y0`.

```
{X[t_], Y[t_]} = {X[t], Y[t]} /. 
  NDSolve[{X'[t] == a*X[t] - b*X[t]*Y[t],
  Y'[t] == -c*Y[t] + d*X[t]*Y[t],
  X[11] == 45.79, 
  Y[11] == 41.4} /. {{a -> 0.197193, b -> 0.00117457,c -> -0.0562289, d -> 0.000277672}}
  ,{X[t], Y[t]}, {t, 0, 11}][[1]];

{X[0],Y[0]}
(* {7.67928, 20.8671} *)
```

Comment: The sum doesn't include the last element in the list because the forward finite difference is not defined there. `Last@dx==Last@x-First@x` is meaningless

Comment: This is just an aside that has nothing to do with the problem at hand but... your first three lines of code can be compacted with `{tt,x,y}=Transpose[data];`

Comment: @Peltio, good point. I usually only think of putting one symbol on the lhs...

Comment: Correction. `Last@dx==First@x-Last@x` is meaningless.

Comment: @TimothyWofford Good job. But I think it is somewhat rough to use FDM(finite difference method) because of big time step. You method(least-squares optimization) can be improved by `findfit`.

Comment: @Kimist, you can post an alternative answer using `FindFit`. You could try interpolating the data and finding a numerical derivative of the interpolation if you think it will be better.

Comment: @TimothyWofford will you supply a plot showing the given data and your fit please.